# Ubuntu 18.04 no internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, dns, dhcp

I have internet connection problems using Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. It's a dual boot with Windows 10, no problem under Windows 10, same router, same router configuration, same laptop, but no internet connection thru my router TL-WR1043ND. Both wireless and LAN connections connedcts to the router but no internet access. However I can ping my gateway/ log in to the router configuration. panel. The router is connected to some sort of a switch for IP TV and internet, provided by my IPS and when I jump my router and connect to that switch thru LAN cable, there is an internet access. I'm not sure if it's router configuration issue, but if so, there would be also no internet connection under Windows 10. Right?

I've read a few answers to similar questions, but since I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux at all, I'm not sure what am I doing or how to do it. For example I tried adding google's DNS adresses in resolv.conf but seems like the changes can't be saved. Whenever I open the file, it's the same lines. Preinstalled Firefox was set to use system proxy setting, changed it to "no proxy" but still no internet access. Date/time are correct, although I noticed some bug - my time zone is GMT+2 and if a set a corecct time in Ubintu, the BIOS time changes two hours back, and vice versa. For the moment it's set to GMT 0 in Ubuntu. Any advice where to start from?

This is output from `systemd-resolve --status`:

Here is when the wifi card is connected to the router without internet access:

```
Link 3 (wlp5s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 212.39.90.42
                      8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Here is the LAN connection to the ISP's switch when I have internet access:

```
Link 2 (enp4s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 212.39.90.42
                      212.39.90.43
                      169.254.9.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

EDIT

Here is the output from `sudo lshw -C network` using LAN connection to my router:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: d8:c4:97:c0:d6:ef
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=169.254.9.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f0900000-f093ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 29
       serial: 94:b8:6d:f3:7a:cd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-26-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:35 memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

EDIT 2

Output form `sudo iptables -L | grep -i OUTPUT`:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

Output from `sudo iptables -L | grep -i INPUT`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

EDIT 3:

What is "Current Scopes" and why using LAN connection to ISP's switch (when I have internet access) it states:

```
Current Scopes: DNS
```

But using wireless connection to my router it states:

```
Current Scopes: none
```

Comment: look at the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`.

Comment: Some clarification required... In Windows 10, does it work properly with BOTH LAN and wireless access? In Ubuntu, does it work with EITHER LAN or wireless?

Comment: @heynnema - both LAN and wireless are working under Windows 10

Comment: @waltinator - what to look for in the logs?

Comment: More clarification required... so Windows works fine... but Ubuntu doesn't work on either LAN or wireless... unless you LAN directly into your ISP's modem, correct? Do you have "Access Control" enabled in the router? Have you rebooted the router?

Comment: @heynnema That's correct, no internet access unless I connect to the IPS's modem thru LAN. "Access Control" is disabled in router settings.

Comment: Have you rebooted the router? In this case, do this by unplugging it, count to 15, replug, retest. Plug in a LAN cable between the computer and the router, and edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: what is the output for `sudo iptables -L | grep -i OUTPUT` and `sudo iptables -L | grep -i INPUT` ?

Comment: @heynnema  Sorry, forgot that part of your question. I've rebooted the router multiple times. Even tried static IP configuration but still no access to internet, I can't ping any IP outside of my network. But now I noticed that when I switch the LAN cable from the ISP's modem to my router or vice versa, I have to wait for about 7 min. to connect to the respective device. Restarting network-manager of switching off/on the LAN card does not help. It's like lack of DHCP. Tested that in Windows 10 - laptop immediately connects to the respective devices.

Comment: @loko OK, if I got this right, in Ubuntu, LAN or wifi access via the router doesn't work, but LAN access via the ISP modem directly works, yes? Hard reset your router to factory specs and set it up again. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

check the OS routes after connecting to the WiFi router, this check can be done with this command `ip route` the result should be something like this [image: example output]

if your output does not look like this, "Remember the numbers can change", then check your router configuration specifically the country set.

Comment: Well, it's the same. Here is the output of `ip route` using wireless connection to my router:
    default via 169.254.9.1 dev wlp5s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp5s0 scope link metric 1000 
    169.254.9.0/24 dev wlp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.9.206 metric 600